# TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

Tags: python, web.py

I have a `main.py` file. When I execute this, it gives me the following error. Does anyone have any clue about this problem? Thanks in advance.

**main.py**

```
urls = ("/poems(.*)", "poem.Poems")
app = web.application( urls, globals() )

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

**Error Message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "memory.py", line 24, in <module>
app = web.application( urls, globals() )
File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web.py-0.40.dev0-   py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 62, in __init__
self.init_mapping(mapping)
File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web.py-0.40.dev0-py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 130, in init_mapping
self.mapping = list(utils.group(mapping, 2))
File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/web.py-0.40.dev0-py2.7.egg/web/utils.py", line 529, in group
seq = iter(seq)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

Comment: My guess, you've got a python file named something web.py is looking for, so it's loading your file rather than it's own.